# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/service/StripeThreeDs2ServiceImpl;

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I am migrating stripe from 3D Secure to 3D Secure 2.

when i update the library to

`com.stripe:stripe-android:10.4.2@aar`

i am getting this error

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/stripe/android/stripe3ds2/service/StripeThreeDs2ServiceImpl;`

when i initialise stripe using this command 
`Stripe(app,KR.strings.stripe_key)`

If somebody can help me with this would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:10.4.2@aar'

Comment: what are you trying to say !